# npm_lifecycle_event different output when updating the version of npm

Tags: typescript, npm, npx

I'm struggling with the output of the npm_lifecycle_event when updating the version of npm.

When I run my code with the following version of npm v6.14.15 my npm_lifecycle is being printed out as following:
`npm_lifecycle_event: 'alive'`

However, when I update my npm version to for example: v8.1.0 my npm_lifecycle is being printed out as following:
`npm_lifecycle_event: 'npx'`

My Scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "alive": "npx playwright test  ..._some_gibberish_for_my_code",
    ...
}
```

The problem only occurs when I execute a script containing an npx command.
But now I'm wondering am I doing something wrong or is this a bug within the newer versions?